# How do I embed a Slack activity feed on a static webpage?

Tags: widget, slack-api

I am planning on replacing a twitter activity feed widget with one that displays activity from a Slack channel.

Does anyone have a preferably free solution for embedding this, preferably that works with Slack free plan?

Comment: Like you can read here in a Questions asked some time after you, there is still no option for this and like I see there still isn't an option even it is already 2017. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041731/embed-slack-on-a-html-page

Answer (score 4):

There are no pre-built solutions for this, but you might want to look into building something using the [RTM API](https://api.slack.com/rtm).