# Embed slack on a html page

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, embed, slack

I am having trouble embedding a slack feed onto a html site.  When I try to use an iframe, it just shows up as a white box.  I have tried using jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"> .       
    </script>
    <script>
$("#testLoad").load("http://www.SlackURLHere");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="testLoad"></div>

    <iframe src="http://www.SlackURLHere"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried with **"http"** and **"https"** on both iframe and jquery with no luck. :( So if you have any other methods please do share!

Thanks

Comment: Can you view the URL for the slack feed in a browser? If so, then its not the URL and you can strike that out as a possible issue.

Comment: Are you really not choosing the double quote after the URL, or was that just a typo?

Comment: Just a typo when copying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just tried this and it looks like the reason it won't display is because of the X-Frame-Options header which is set by slack.com to be SAMEORIGIN. In other words, you're only allowed to embed that page when on slack.com, not anywhere else.

Comment: You could do so many interesting things with slack if you could integrate it into your own webpage. Really waiting for this feature!

Comment: You could ajax a script on your own domain that retrieves the markup for you.

iframe.html > proxy.php > slack.com/stuff

Answer (score -3):

You forgot to close the quotes  on your `iframe source`. Otherwise it will work
Also you are closing the div too early. Close it after the iframe and not before.
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeqhk664/)

[image: iframe image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but it doesn't seem to work when changing the url to our slack url. (the jsfiddle) the iframe is just a white box >_<  If you know why this is happening then please do tell me.

Comment: could be an issue with the data being retrieved from the server and not the code. Does the debug console say anything?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

using https instead of http is still giving the same error

Comment: As per above comments, even if the syntax was correct, it still won't work due to X-Frame-Options security restrictions